# How to copy a object's list to another object's list

Tags: c++, list

I want to copy all attributes, lists and subtrees from one object to another object. However I am not able to copy the list with all its elements. How should I do it?

```
SPSTTree copyTree(SPSTTree original)
{

    SPSTTree copy = (SPSTTree) malloc(sizeof(SPSTNode));

    // Copy non-pointer values
    copy->Element = original->Element;
    copy->offset = original->offset;
    copy->qtd_element = original->qtd_element;
    copy->list = original->list; // HOW TO COPY ALL THE ELEMENTS IN THE LIST??

    // Recursively copy subtrees
    if(original->lchild) {
        copy->lchild = copyTree(original->lchild);
    } else {
        copy->lchild = NULL;
    }
    if(original->rchild) {
        copy->rchild = copyTree(original->rchild);
    } else {
        copy->rchild = NULL;
    }

    return copy;
}
```

Definition of  SPSTNode and ElementList

```
struct ElementList{
    int value;
    int position;
};

struct SPSTNode{
    ElementType Element;
    int64_t offset;
    SPSTTree lchild;
    SPSTTree rchild;

    int qtd_element = 1; // usado para multiplicidade em caso de duplicidade na inserção
    std::list<ElementList> list; //(Element, position)

};
```

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor? If not, maybe that's a big part of the solution.

Comment: What is the definition of `SPSTTree`?  You code is C code, and you should not use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: My code is C++. It's just a code snippet.

Comment: focus on the problem please.

Comment: How you copy the list depends greatly on the definition of `list`, which is part of `SPSTTree`, which I have requested and you have not provided.

Comment: One problem is that you use `malloc`. It's (almost) useless for anything but trivially copyable objects - which `SPSTTree` is not. You can have alignment errors. The constructor will not get called and the destructor won't get called when you `free` either. Please provide a [mcve] so we can see and compile the relevant code.

Comment: I put the definition above. This is a struct. I want to copy all of its elements, as it is a data structure that will query in a binary tree. Then, with each query, the tree changes its structure. I'm copying the object to keep the tree the same for each query. This is working. But I wanted to add a list to that object and I can't copy it.

Comment: What is `SPSTTree`? We can't compile this. Make a [mcve].

Comment: `SPSTNode` _needs_ to be constructed (allocated with `new`), which is why you shouldn't use `malloc` here.  The `list` member has a constructor which needs to run before you can do anything with it.

Comment: It's a binary tree. It's a kind of AVL-Tree. I just want to copy all elements of a list to another object that contains a list with the same type. I want to know if there is a simpler way to do this than by scanning the entire list and copying all the elements.

Comment: Will you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: This question is a continuation of this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962323/how-to-store-an-object-inside-another-object-without-modifying-the-original-usin

Comment: That question doesn't contain enough code either. I noticed that the one answer you got to that question may have been the reason for the `malloc` you are using. Unlearn that for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy the list.

```cpp
std::copy(original->list.begin(), original->list.end(), std::back_inserter(copy->list));
```

The malloc is a problem, because you skip object creation. Are you somehow interfacing C-code and forced to do such a thing? From your snippet it looks like you could use [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<SPSTTree> copyTree(const SPSTTree& original)
{

    auto copy = std::make_unique<SPSTTree>();
...
}
```